# Tweet Every 30 Minutes

Tags: twitter, tweepy, tweets, twitter-api-v2

i have a bot to create tweets, and i would like to run it every 30 minutes.

so far i run it just for testing via Terminal like this: `PS C:\Users\XXX>  python "C:\Users\xxx\module1.py"`
this is the actual bot code:

```
from typing import Text
import tweepy
import random

from tweepy import Response, tweet
client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key="XXXXXX",
    consumer_secret="XXXXXX",
    access_token="XXXXXX",
    access_token_secret="XXXXXX"
)

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import webbrowser

while True:
    url = requests.get("https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "html.parser")
    title = soup.find(class_="firstHeading").text
    printed = print(title)
    break
try:
   client.create_tweet(text="לשטח את " + title)
   print("וואלה יופי הצלחת יא בתול")
   print("יא קינג יא אלוף אין עליך יא גאון מחשבים")
except tweepy.errors.TweepyException as e:
   print("שגיאה על הראש שלך")
   print("יא אפס")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to create a tweet every 30 minutes, you can set up a `CRON job` to execute the task at that interval.

Additionally, remember to use a different title each time, as tweets from the same account cannot have the same title.

Comment: how do i set it up? (windows 11)

Comment: I'll share steps in 2 parts:
first part:
   (1) Press `Win + S` on your keyboard & Type "Task Scheduler" and press Enter.

   (2) In the right-hand pane, click on "Create Basic Task..." or "Create Task...".

   (3) In the "General" tab, provide a name for your task (e.g., "Tweet Scheduler").

   (4) Select "Run with highest privileges" if your script requires elevated privileges.

   (5) Go to the "Triggers" tab and click "New...".

   (6) Select "Daily" and set the repeat interval to every 30 minutes.

   (7) Set the duration to "1 day".

Comment: Second part: 

   (8) Go to the "Actions" tab and click "New..." to create a new action.

   (9) Select "Start a program" as the action type.

   (10) Browse and select the Python executable (`python.exe`).

   (11) In the "Add arguments" field, provide the path to your Python script.

   (12) Click "OK" to save the task.

   (13) You can manually run the task to test if it's working as expected.

Please ensure that the Python executable and your script's path are correctly specified in the task action.

Comment: it worked for a couple of hours (i did repeat every 30 min) and suddenly i got "too many requests" error and "Rate limit exceeded. Sleeping for 900 seconds."